How do I calculate gas pressure loss rate for a given hole diameter
I am coding a simulation of a space station, including the temperature, pressure, etc of the air in each module of the station. I'm modelling this using the ideal gas law, i.e. I have a (fixed) volume for each module, an initial pressure and temperature, and therefore a number of moles of gas.
I'd like to be able to simulate the effects of a leak in a module. Given a hole diameter, I want to approximate how many moles of air are lost per second. I guess I could also express this as drop in pressure per second, and derive the moles lost? Is there an existing equation that approximates this?
I found this online calculator (https://toolbox.tlv.com/global/TI/calculator/air-flow-rate-through-orifice.html), but I can't really follow the maths as it's expressed there, and it gives a flow rate in volume of gas, which feels weird because surely the volume would depend on the pressure, right?
Edit: I've made some progress, which I'll post here in the interests of helping future googlers:
This page was very helpful: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/mflchk.html
I believe this problem can be fairly well approximated by this "choked flow" calculation. Venting into space, it seems the air will pretty much always be leaking at "sonic" speeds, where the limiting factor is the speed of sound. That means that many of the complex factors can be replaced with constants. I hacked together some Python code that more-or-less replicates the results of the calculator on that page.

The flow rate will also depend on the pressure difference between inlet and outlet, given space that will probably be the lowest outlet pressure possible. You should check for other expressions of calculating flow.

Might be of interest NASA confirms space station cracking a “highest” risk and consequence problem
